# prevent unique constraint violations in clustered architecture

Tags: database, replication

im working with four app servers and two database instances (3DNS and BigIP determine what app server a user is directed to based on usage etc). Two app servers per database node. The database instances stay synchronized using replication.

However, when a new user first visits the application it uses SSO to get a their identification and automatically registers that user. This is a problem if say the user opens two browser at the same time , both pointing to my application. The app will try to register the user on both databases, then when replication runs it will throw a unique constraint exception.

Is there any way to manage database access in this type of architecture so that certain tables, like user registration, can only be accessed if a flag has been obtained?

thanks, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with row-level locking, however I am not sure if this question is appropriate for SF or should be moved to SO? Seems like an app architecture thing, regardless of the underlying setup and/or hardware.

Comment: cheers will move